# Cleaning data in R : Error missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed

Tags: r

So I have been trying to clean my raw data by changing 0, - and empty values to NA.

testing is the raw data and it's all in factor since I got it from a csv file.

When I run this code,

```
test <- matrix(0,216,111)

for(i in 1:216) {
  for(j in 1:111) {

    if(testing[i,j]== "0") {
      test[i,j] <- gsub("0","NA",testing[i,j])
    } else if(testing[i,j] == "-") {
      test[i,j] <- gsub("-","NA",testing[i,j])
    } else if(testing[i,j] == "") {
      test[i,j] <- gsub("","NA",testing[i,j])
    } else {
      test[i,j] <- testing[i,j]
    }
  }
}
```

This error appears when I run the code.

```
Error in if (testing[i, j] == 0) { : 
missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed
```

What should I do to solve this problem?

Comment: Maybe use na.strings in read.table (see `?read.table`) or whichever function you are using to read in the data. Btw, your code should not run, since testing is not created. Presumably, you see that error because testing somehow has smaller dimensions than test.

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
test <- matrix(0,216,111)

for(i in 1:216) {
  for(j in 1:111) {

    if(test[i,j]== "0") {
      test[i,j] <- gsub("0","NA",test[i,j])
    } else if(test[i,j] == "-") {
      test[i,j] <- gsub("-","NA",test[i,j])
    } else if(test[i,j] == "") {
      test[i,j] <- gsub("","NA",test[i,j])
    } else {
      test[i,j] <- test[i,j]
    }
  }
}
```

The problem was that you didn't test for the correct data! This means you tested for `testing`, although you needed `test`. However, instead of loops you can also use `apply`:

```
apply(test, 2, function(x){gsub("0","NA",x)})
```

Comment: testing is where i stored the data.

Comment: then you should've supplied us with a sample of the data you're testing. However, you might try apply and see if the error still appears.

Answer (score 0):

It is probably caused by `NA` values in `testing`. If you compare `NA` to `"0"` it will return `NA` which is not a `logical` value and can therefore not be evaluated by `if`. You could use the `isTRUE` function which will return `FALSE` if `testing[i][j]` is `NA`:

```
test <- matrix(0,216,111)

for(i in 1:216) {
  for(j in 1:111) {

    if(isTRUE(testing[i,j]== "0"))is {
      test[i,j] <- gsub("0","NA",testing[i,j])
     } else if(testing[i,j] == "-") {
       test[i,j] <- gsub("-","NA",testing[i,j])
     } else if(testing[i,j] == "") {
       test[i,j] <- gsub("","NA",testing[i,j])
    } else {
      test[i,j] <- testing[i,j]
    }
   }
  }
```